# Rails 4 Error: Getting Parameters from URL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, url, rubygems

I am fairly new to rails and I am struggling getting the id param out of this url:

```
http://localhost:3000/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=13
```

Userflow:

1. Form to setup their Job (below / Job Model) =>

   ```
   redirect_to "/subscriberjobs/new?job_id=#{@job.id}"
   ```
2. (Job Controller) => Getting Payment via Stripe
3. (Subscriberjobs Controller) => Update the values of this Job.

The last step does not work. On the one hand it always redirects to `/subscriberjobs/1` and on the other hand it does not update the Values (neither for Job 1 nor Job 13)

Currently I am using this code to get it: (Subscriberjobs Controller)

```
def update
  @job = Job.find_by(id: params[:id])

  @job.is_active = true
  @job.is_featured = false
  @job.stripe_id = customer.id
  @job.save

  token = params[:stripeToken]

  customer = Stripe::Customer.create(
      card: token,
      plan: 1004,
      email: current_user.email
      )
  redirect_to root_path
end
```

The Form:

```
= simple_form_for @job do |f|
  = f.input :company, required: true
  = f.input :title, required: true
  = f.input :job_filename
  = f.input :location, required: true
  = f.input :sort
  = f.input :tag_list, required: true
  = f.input :content_one
  = f.input :content_two
  = f.input :content_three
  = f.hidden_field :job_id, value: params[:id]
  = f.button :submit
```

Any help on how to achieve what I am trying to do is much appreciated!

Comment: by default/convention, you will always find ids in rails like that `subscriberjobs/id`, and then you just access it like `params[:id]`. In this case, you're also including `job_id` in your form, the thing here is that `simple_form_for` wraps the content from the form inside a `job` key in your `params`, so, you need to access it like `params[:job][:job_id]`.

Comment: I am not quite sure if that's what you meant: `@job = Job.find_by(id: params[:job][:job_id])`, but that creates this error: `NoMethodError in SubscriberjobsController#update
undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Comment: your `simple_form_for` form is the one that fires the `update` that doesn't work, right ?. If so, would you mind pasting what you have in the rails log when that action gets triggered ?.

Comment: That's right. Here are the logs: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/kjgaih91ye7lr6p/AAA96hj7_-q7ZK3EemGt6tj9a?dl=0 - from loading the Form to the error after paying via Stripe :) Hope that helps

Comment: I see, there are some requests being made and at some point the update `/subscriberjobs/1` happens, just use `@job = Job.find_by(id: params[:id])` instead of `@job = Job.find_by(id: params[:job_id])`

Comment: Hmm.. that fixes the error but the main problem which is that the values aren't getting updated is still there. I remember that I already did what you suggest.

Comment: I can see in the response that you do get `stripeToken`, perhaps the `@job.save` is failing, put a `binding.pry` or `byebug`(whatever you use) after that line and check if there are any validation errors with `@job.errors`.

Comment: I figured something out! The `@job.save` works perfectly. Instead it just always updates the Job with `id == 1`. I don't know why but that should help. I made a full `db:reset`  and if I create a new Job and pay for it, the values change as intended - just only for the first one